# Is it possible to view Record Zone Subscriptions (CKRecordZoneSubscription) in icloud dashboard

Tags: cloudkit

When I added a Query Subscription to my database, it showed up in the "Subscription Types" area of the iCloud Dashboard.  I changed to using a Zone Subscription, which doesn't seem to show anywhere.

If I check for subscriptions using fetchAllSubscriptionsWIthCompletionHandler I >DO< get the subscription back, so I know it is present.  But it doesn't show up in the Subscription Type panel (see attached screenshot - I whited out identifying info that doesn't pertain to the question)

Is this a dashboard issue, or is there some way to view custom Zone types of subscriptions that I am unaware of?  The documentation is woefully vague.

TIA[image]